# Extract table data from Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia-api

is there any way to extract only table data I am trying to extract a table from the specific section "Grade One" from this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_motor_racing_circuits_by_FIA_grade using Api sandbox but I am getting only the whole content of the page.

this is the URL from the API sandbox which gives me all content.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=List%20of%20motor%20racing%20circuits%20by%20FIA%20grade&prop=text

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps I described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71528754/12511801) in order to get the data you want.

This is the URL:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=List%20of%20motor%20racing%20circuits%20by%20FIA%20grade&prop=sections%7Ctext&section=1&disablelimitreport=1&utf8=1
```

The output contains the table and the text in the "Grade One" section.

This is the [API Sandbox example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=List%20of%20motor%20racing%20circuits%20by%20FIA%20grade&prop=sections%7Ctext&section=1&disablelimitreport=1&utf8=1).

Response:

```
{
    "parse": {
        "title": "List of motor racing circuits by FIA grade",
        "pageid": 57151782,
        "text": {
            "*": "<div class=\"mw-parser-output\"><h2><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Grade_One\">Grade One</span><span class=\"mw-editsection\"><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">[</span><a href=\"/w/index.php?title=List_of_motor_racing_circuits_by_FIA_grade&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1\" title=\"Edit section: Grade One\">edit</a><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">]</span></span></h2>\n<p>There are 40 Grade One circuits for a total of 49 layouts in 27 nations as of December 2021. Circuits holding Grade One certification may host events involving \"Automobiles of Groups D (FIA International Formula) and E (Free Formula) with a weight/power ratio of less than 1 kg/hp.\"<sup id=\"cite_ref-ISC2019_1-0\" class=\"reference\"><a href=\"#cite_note-ISC2019-1\">&#91;1&#93;</a></sup> As such, a Grade One certification is required to host events involving <a href=\"/wiki/Formula_One\" title=\"Formula One\">Formula One</a> cars.<sup id=\"cite_ref-2\" class=\"reference\"><a href=\"#cite_note-2\">&#91;2&#93;</a></sup><sup id=\"cite_ref-2021_December_list_3-0\" class=\"reference\"><a href=\"#cite_note-2021_December_list-3\">&#91;3&#93;</a></sup>\n</p>\n<table class=\"wikitable sortable\" width=\"75%\" style=\"font-size: 95%;\">\n<tbody><tr>\n<th>Circuit\n</th>\n<th>Location\n</th>\n<th>Country\n</th>\n<th>Layout\n</th>\n<th>Length\n</th>\n<th>Continent\n</th></tr>\n<tr>\n<td><a href=\"/wiki/Albert_Park_Circuit\" title=\"Albert Park Circuit\">Albert Park Circuit</a>\n</td>\n<td><a href=\"/wiki/Melbourne\" title=\"Melbourne\">Melbourne</a>\n</td>\n<td><span class=\"flagicon\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/23px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png\" decoding=\"async\" width=\"23\" height=\"12\" class=\"thumbborder\" srcset=\"//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/35px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png 2x\" data-file-width=\"1280\" data-file-height=\"640\" />&#160;</span><a href=\"/wiki/Australia\" title=\"Australia\">Australia</a>\n</td>\n<td>Grand Prix\n</td>\n<td>5.279&#160;km (3.280&#160;mi)\n</td>\n<td>Australia\n</td></tr>\n<tr>[...the rest of the table is shown here]"
        },
        "sections": [
            {
                "toclevel": 1,
                "level": "2",
                "line": "Grade One",
                "number": "1",
                "index": "1",
                "fromtitle": "List_of_motor_racing_circuits_by_FIA_grade",
                "byteoffset": 0,
                "anchor": "Grade_One"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I can't see how you can return the table *only*, so, you have to extract the table from the API response (*by using a script*).